# Install R packages through "Jobs" tab in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio, I usually install `R` packages using the console by `install.packages('pkg-name')` command.
However, when some `R` packages are required in an R script, Rstudio opens a pop-up and asks if I want to install those packages. If I click on "Install", it starts installing those packages inside the "Jobs" tab. This is particularly useful for me because my internet is slow and while a large package is being installed I can continue my works on the console tab. I want to know if there is any way to always install packages through this "Jobs" tab, without using the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an R package [`{job}`](https://lindeloev.github.io/job/) which can be used to run any r code directly from a script or console. To install a package as a Rstudio job:

```
# install.packages("job")

job::job({
  install.packages("pkg_name")
})
```

Also `{job}` provides Rstudio Addins to easily run selected code as a job.
see [here](https://lindeloev.github.io/job/) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script, let's call it `temp.R` and include the `install.packages` command in it. Something like :

```
install.packages('dplyr', repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages('tidyr', repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

You can click on `Start Local Job`

[image]

and point to the location of the script and adjust any other setting that you want.

[image]

Now click on `Start` and use R/RStudio while the script finishes in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will accept it. However, typing `repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"` every time is not very handy. Is there any way to set a global repository so that `install.packages('pkg-name')` would be enough for the job?

Comment: If there are lot of packages you can always set up a `for` loop or `lapply` to do the work so that you don't have to copy-paste `repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"` everytime. See this answer on how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830451/3962914

Comment: Why do you say to specify the repo every time? I install packages through jobs with just `install.packages("package_name")` and it works fine with my default repo

Comment: @stlba Well, it didn't for me hence I specified the repo.